# Echo X text lines and remove

Tags: php

I have a .txt file that contains multiple lines of text.

```
Lorem
Ipsum
Dolor
Sit
Amet
```

I'd like when the PHP page with a defined number (?n=3*) in the URL is visited, that number lines of code from the text file is displayed and deleted?

i.e: ?n=2 displays:

```
Lorem
Ipsum
```

The .txt file now contain:

```
Dolor
Sit
Amet
```

Comment: Start with code that reads the file

Comment: _"I'd like"_ - fine. And what have you done to please your like?

Comment: Please don't forget to select an answer for your question! So everybody can see that the question is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `file`, `array_splice`, `implode` and `file_put_contents`

```
$fileAsArray = file('yourfile.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$extractedLines = array_splice($fileAsArray, 0, $_GET['n']);
file_put_contents('yourfile.txt', implode(PHP_EOL, $fileAsArray));
foreach($extractedLines as $line)
  echo $line.PHP_EOL;
```